# Весь сайт при приближении имеет отступ, который не прописан в коде

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не могу разобраться. Почему если уменьшить [этот сайт](http://helapay.net) и пролистать вправо (или зайти с телефона), то появляется какой-то непонятный отступ слева ? Даже огда я задаю точную ширину всем элементам, ничего не меняется. В чём проблема ?

Comment: что значит _уменьшить_?

Comment: `box-sizing`...

Comment: @Grund сделать окно браузера меньшим.

Comment: @Other а что с ним не так ?

Comment: Не знаю, но стоило мне убрать это свойство, глюк ушёл. Да и как-то странно назначать его всем элементам. Не используйте селектор `*`: он тормознутый из-за того, что это **все** элементы и нет свойств, которые действительно **нужны** всем.